# Save order of entries with JCache implementation

Tags: java, jcache

I want to cache the content in a DB table like below, on the Java heap of an JavaEE application server.

```
| group   | key     | value                                  |
| ------- | ------- | -------------------------------------- |
| CHAR(3) | CHAR(5) | VARCHAR(256)                           |
| ------- | ------- | -------------------------------------- |
| 001     | 0       | male                                   |
| 001     | 1       | female                                 |
| 001     | 9       | other                                  |
| 002     | 004     | Afghanistan                            |
| 002     | 008     | Albania                                |
| 002     | 010     | Antarctica                             |
| 002     | 012     | Algeria                                |
| ...     | ...     | ...                                    |
| 003     | LAX     | Los Angeles International Airport      |
| 003     | SIN     | Singapore Changi International Airport |
| ...     | ...     | ...                                    |
```

I think the JCache is most general way for those purposes, but how can I save the order of these records in the cache, like LinkedHashMap?

(The configuration for specific JCache implementation is acceptable.)

**EDIT**

This is a typical One True Lookup Table (OTLT) in the legacy enterprise application now I am working on. The primary sort key is `group`, and secondary sort key is `key`.

OTLT has some disadvantages in performance, so I want to use use cache mechanism as a countermeasure to this disadvantages.

Comment: "order" is based on some "key". Db table in own sense , JChache in similar. I guess, some connection group+"string key" is Your JCache key???

Comment: Example show, You have some trouble with type of "key", not string, not number ... like adding apples to peaches

Comment: Just as you said, this table layout is somehow weird. But this kind of OTLT-style tables often appear in the legacy enterprise application. I add some information in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you need to cache what looks like a map-of-maps model I would suggest you take also into account your access pattern (ie how your application reads these data). My *guess* is that you would need to do two things with these data:

1. list all values available in a single group (eg to populate a "Country" drop-down)
2. locate a single value by group and key (to display a user's "Country" in their profile page)

Given these *assumed* requirements, these are fulfilled with a `Cache<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>>` structure. Use the `group` as the cache's key and a `LinkedHashMap<String, String>` of all `key`->`value` mappings in that group as the cache's value. In this arrangement, requirement 1 is fulfilled with a single lookup in the `Cache`, while requirement 2 is fulfilled with one lookup in the `Cache` (to obtain the `LinkedHashMap` key->value mappings) and one more lookup in the `LinkedHashMap`. Note that instead of a `LinkedHashMap` as the cache's value type you can use a `TreeMap`, essentially any kind of map that maintains iteration order will do.

Due to requirement 1, I would avoid a group/key mangling scheme (like using `group + "-" + key` as you cache's key) as it would require a full iteration of the cache's entry set (with `Cache.iterator()`) and pattern matching each one of the keys to decide whether it belongs to the group you're looking for or not.

The JCache-standard way to create such a `Cache` with the above configuration would be something like this:

```
MutableConfiguration<String, LinkedHashMap> config = new MutableConfiguration<String, LinkedHashMap>()
         .setTypes(String.class, LinkedHashMap.class);
CachingProvider provider = Caching.getCachingProvider();
CacheManager defaultCacheManager = provider.getCacheManager();
Cache<String, LinkedHashMap> cache = defaultCacheManager
        .createCache("cache", config);
```

Observe that due to Java generics limitations, it is not possible to do this:

```
MutableConfiguration<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>> config = new MutableConfiguration<String, LinkedHashMap<String, String>()
        .setTypes(String.class, LinkedHashMap<String, String>.class);
```

Also, you may consider implementing a [`CacheLoader`](https://github.com/jsr107/jsr107spec/blob/37937a43c66b986dbfc0aa8291c8f10975b26dc0/src/main/java/javax/cache/integration/CacheLoader.java#L35) to have your cache populated from the lookup table, as well as a strategy for refreshing your cache contents (either via expiry or by explicitly evicting the cache contents).